# Why VS Code is not showing intellisense anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Recently, I copy paste a react app folder from another computer to my new one. But now when I work with VS Code, the intelissense does not work and keep loading. See below an example:

[image]

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This happens at times. Its some issue with VS code itself
I fixed it either by restarting VS code or the restarting the system itself.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have tried several times to close and open Vs Code and it did not solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and how to solve it.
The intelissense of VS code does not work when your installation and your code are not on the same drive. In my case the VS Code was on C and the code was on D drive.
When I moved my code to C drive, everything began to work normally.